# AWS SDK cannot find class

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK to update a DynamoDB table. I am following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPITablesExample.html) documentation example from AWS. However, the class Table cannot be found. This also applies to what should be the methods in Table such as getTable(), updateTable(), waitForActive(), etc.

My gradle is compiled as follows

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sdb:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.2.+'
}
```

as per the [setup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html)

The AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/util/Tables.html) indicates that Class Tables is derived from: 
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.Tables. 
Importing this does not work.

Comment: Care to share the actual code throwing the error?

Comment: You can maybe take a look at this sample: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class Table can't be found because it is not accessible for Android.

See here to confirm:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/

Instead, you can use dynamodbmapper or the low level api, examples:

Mapper:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.CRUDExample1.html

Low-level api:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito/src/com/amazonaws/demo/userpreferencesom/DynamoDBManager.java